# Can I ignore Highcharts Error #15 untill the functionality is working as expected

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart which has both columnRange and column in it. Initially I had few problems in building the data but later I managed to get what I expected to see. The issue is I see a lot of highcharts error #15 in the console which is a data sorting issue as per documentation. How can I get rid of them or Can I ignore them ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't ignore the Highcharts error #15, everything may seem fine at first, but bugs may arise with chart interactions. To get rid of the error just sort your data before creating the chart.

```
    var data = [
        [5, 9],
        [1, 11],
        [2, 13]
    ];

    data.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fh56vqpo/